# this."FunctionName" is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, jsx

I would like using a function in the render() who will be calling multiple time because it's call for each element of a Map(). But for some reasons my function is not recognized correctly, I get the error :

> this.IsHeStillAlive is not a function

I totally rewrote my post to make it easier to understand and here is the link for my exemple on SandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/test-uz-713xy.
in this exemple I try to use the functions "IsHeStillAlive" and "SwitchButton".

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone outside this forum find me a solution.

The correction is in my sandbox link but if one day the lin is dead ...

just in case here are the step to correct my issue:

1. move your methods out of the class,make them a function components in the same file.
2. change the panel param to props . Inside props will be a panel prop
3. render the components like

it will not be very explicit if the sandbox link is dead but that will maybe help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as the following:

```
<div className="slave">
    <h3>{panel.price}€</h3><br/>
    {
       panel.name === 'Basique' ?
          <Button className="buttonStore"
                  onClick={() => { this.UnsubcribeIt() }}>
              Unsubscribe
          </Button> :
          <Button className="buttonStore"
                  onClick={() => { this.buyit(licenceName) }}>
              Buy Now
          </Button>
    }
</div>
```

Or shorter in the first `<Button />` as `onClick={this.UnsubcribeIt}`.

Comment: Yeah I already try it actually, but I want remove "Basique" by "This.TalkToBackend()" function and it doesn't work neither like that ... I will edit my Code

Comment: @Xodarap Maybe you can create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for easier debug and help.

Comment: I will try to make one, it will be probably easier to understand yes

Comment: well I made a sandbox sample but for some reason he doesn't work yet : https://codesandbox.io/s/upgradefile-5p5rd

Comment: I made a new exemple on Sandbox and this time it work. you can find the link in my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should extract `dataGet` first so it wont have confusing this

```
render(){
let {dataGet} = this.state
  return (
  {this.state.dataGet.map(mapPanel)}
  )
}
```

tell me if that is working

Comment: I just tried and I get some error who I don't know how to fix ... "function" looks like the reason of the errors

Comment: this is what i did. tell me if it works [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/upgradefile-forked-dtqo7?file=/src/test.js)

Comment: I just try to edit my code like your exemple but I get the same error message

Comment: it's the same, Cannot read property 'SwitchButton' of undefined